# Complicated Fitting Layout In CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I have two sections with contents, ordered vertically:

```
+-------+
|   A   |
+-------+
|   B   |
+-------+
```

I need section A to have an undefined height (grow and shrink depends on it's own contents).

Section B on the other hand has to fill the remaining height of screen.

It was easy if section A had a static height so i would do:

```
.A{
    height:200px;
}
.B{
    height:calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

How can i achieve this when section A has a dynamic height?
I know it can be done with JS with clientHeight/offsetHeight properties, but i prefer a css-only solution.

P.S. Bootstrap is included.

**EDIT**:

The container of those two sections is a [slick-carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) list item.

Sample:

```js
$('.A').each(function(index, elem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.random() * 4000; i++)
    elem.innerHTML += 'A ';
});
$('.B').each(function(index, elem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.random() * 4000; i++)
    elem.innerHTML += 'B ';
});
$('#carousel').slick();
```

```css
#carousel {
  width: 200px;
  max-height:300px;
}

.A {
  background-color: green;
}

.B {
  background-color: brown;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<ul id="carousel">
  <li>
    <section class="A"></section>
    <section class="B"></section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <section class="A"></section>
    <section class="B"></section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <section class="A"></section>
    <section class="B"></section>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is flexbox an option?

Comment: yes, as it widely supported in browsers nowadays.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Then you can achieve this with flex

Comment: Bootstrap 3 (3.3.4)

Comment: Take a look http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. I am embedding it in my screen and will let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason i cannot make this work. adding more info to question.

Comment: what is the parent of A & B ?why not set a fixed height of 100vh or 100%(if possible) to the parent container?

Comment: @karthick: I have edited the question with a snippet which demonstrate the whole DOM structure. setting to 100%/vh doesn't seem to help

Comment: @Dorad: is it ok to have scroll bar for the entire  'li' rather than section .b alone ?

Comment: @karthick: Section a must be entirely shown all the time (in my real code section a is an header), so i can't have a scrollbar for the entire li. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the height to the slick containers in order to enforce the height to the li.

```
.slick-track, .slick-track li, .slick-track li div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can then use flexbox to create the column and give the shrink and grow to the section b

```
.B {
  background-color: brown;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Js fiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/Lqzg3tj2/

Comment: Working with some modifications related to other CSS rules which collide with yours. Thanks.